# How do I convert file to image in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, image-processing, asp.net-core

.NET 4.6 etc I would do something like this...

`var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);`

I have an uploaded file (`IFormFile file`)

If this is an image (png or jpeg) I need to determine the image dimensions.

I'm not sure what library I should be looking at.

Thanks.

**Update**

OK so .NET Core does not include image processing but there are a number of third-party libraries available - these are described [here](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/01/net-core-imaging)

Comment: Downvoters, there is no System.Drawing.Image in .NET Core. There are a [lot of libraries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/) in various stages of development, with different cross-platform dependencies,  that may or may not be suitable when one wants to inspect a file.  This is a valid question

Comment: I have MVC Controller and Views added to my Razor .NET Core C# web application. It handles PayPal payments but I am thinking could I use this Controller with Views to upload and manipulate images using System.Drawing? I have many examples in MVC I have created to manipulate images. Just can't seem to get anything working for my new Razor Core .NET C# website.

Answer (score 6):

Using library: https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("foo.jpg"))
    {
        Image image = new Image(stream);
    }
```

Comment: Still in prerelease as of 3/2020, but seems to have activity and is promptly responding to issues.

Comment: Yeah, if I had an Enterprise level website this would be a good deal but I can't afford $80 a month for a not for profit project that I need image manipulation for.